# copying a file over to a destination then using the where-object -like command not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a file over to a destination but use the `where-object {$_.name -like '*DEA 052020*'}`

Here is my current script but it just ends up copying over the PDF RECON CENTER to the destination:

```
cd \\sageshare\share\
Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*DEA 052020*'}
$SourceDir = "\\Sageshare\share\Reconciliation\PDF Recon Center\$_"
copy-item -path $SourceDir -destination "\\Sageshare\share\Reconciliation\Account Rec. Sheets\Separate Accounts\DEA"
```

Still really new to working with powershell scripting so I am not sure how to place the `$_.Name` in the `$SourceDir`.

Comment: So running where-object on a line by itself is supposed to do something?

Comment: wow, way to live up to the snobby egotistical IT guy personality

Answer (score 0):

Before you perform your where clause, you need to pass something into it.  It doesn't know what you're doing.  You will need to list the contents of the share directory first, and then perform your where clause.

```
Get-ChildItem \\sageshare\share\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*DEA 052020*'}
```

If you want to recursively search, then pass in the `-recurse` switch to your `Get-ChildItem` command, like so

```
Get-ChildItem \\sageshare\share\ -recurse
```

From there you can pipe your `Copy-Item` command into your destination, like so

```
Get-ChildItem \\sageshare\share\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*DEA 052020*'} | Copy-Item -destination "\\Path\To\Destination"
```

Comment: So do you add any part of the $_.Name in the source directory?  So I have many files with the name DEA RECON 05292020.pdf some are different dates than the 29th and I just want it to copy over all DEA pdf files that have the 05 month and 2020 year in it.  So if I run               Get-ChildItem "\\Sageshare\share\reconciliation\PDF Recon Center\$_" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*DEA 052020*'} | Copy Item "\\Sageshare\share\reconciliation\Account Rec. Sheet\Seperate Accounts\DEA"       I always end up just getting a new folder called PDF Recon Center instead of DEA files in the destination

Comment: No, you don't add "$_" into the source directory.  "$_" only works when you have it with a piped command, it won't do anything on it's own.  You just need to take out the "$_" you put in, and it should work.